# Find non scientific notation value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to find a cell with a certain value in Excel 2013 using vba. I have tried this which works fine as long as the column is wide enough.

```
Set foundCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(What:="201402", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

However, if the column is not wide enough the number is shown in scientific notation, "2E+05", which will not be found by the above row, if I search for the value in non-scientific notation. This will work as long as the cell contains the value and not a formula:

```
Set foundCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(What:="201402", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

However, in my case the cell value is a formula referencing another cell ("=C1"), in which case neither of the above will work.

So, is it possible to search for "201402" and find it in row 2, in the following scenario?

1. Create a new workbook in Excel 2013
2. Insert 201402 in cell C1
3. Insert =C1 in cell C2
4. Make column C narrow enough so that scientific notation is shown

Neither of this will work:

```
Set foundCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(2).Find(What:="201402", LookIn:=xlValues)
Set foundCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(2).Find(What:="201402", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

Comment: I'm quite surprised I've never come across this before! I can think of a few workarounds, although I suspect they are not really what you are hoping for. The first is to edit the cell with the value with an apostrophe at the start ('201402). This will force it to text. The next is to autofit the column so it is big enough for the number you are entering. The third is to create a procedure that loops through the cells in your range and checks the value of each cell. It really depends what you prefer to do with it.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the suggested workarounds. The third one is acceptable in my case (as also suggested by user3709402).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like the following

```
Sub FindThis()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Cells
    If c.Value = "201402" Then
        c.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```